# Shouldn't a @ref= be set when OnParametersSetAsync() is called?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In my razor file I have:

```
<EditForm Model="@ConfirmPhoneModel" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync" Context="EditFormContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <CustomValidation @ref="CustomValidation" />
```

And then in my code behind I have:

```
public CustomValidation? CustomValidation { get; private set; }
```

I need to initialize the `CustomValidation` object. I first went to do so in `OnParametersSetAsync()` but it is null when that method is first entered. What's even weirder, part way down in the code it is non-null.

Can I not depend an `@ref` values being set in `OnParametersSetAsync()`? And if so, is the correct place to initialize the object in `OnAfterRenderAsync()`? Or am I not understanding something or doing something wrong.

---

Per @HH's answer below, here are the two use cases I have:

1. Based on the user login I have two different error messages I want to put up as form validation errors/messages. I show these using the CustomValidation child component. There is no action or variable change that occurs when the page is rendered. It's a very simple form with a textbox and a button. And the errors are based on the logged in user.
2. In a child component I need to set `Value = ((IIncludesAddressModel)Context.Model).AddressModel;`. Context is a `[Parameter]` set by the containing component. For this one do I watch for Context being set in `SetParametersAsync()`?

---

In case it helps, here's my code:

```
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    try
    {
        // all of the below depends on CustomValidation being set
        CustomValidation?.ClearErrors();

        var user = (await LoggedInUser.GetCombinedUser(Principal))?.IdentityUser;
        if (user == null)
        {
            var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { "user", new List<string> { "Please log in first to then confirm your phone number." } }
            };
            CustomValidation?.DisplayErrors(errors);
            return;
        }
        _identityUserId = user.Id;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.PhoneNumber))
        {
            ConfirmPhoneModel.RawNumber = user.PhoneNumber;
            ConfirmPhoneModel.DisplayNumber = await SmsService.FormatPhoneNumber(user.PhoneNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            ConfirmPhoneModel.DisplayNumber = "{unknown}";
            var errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
            {
                { "user", new List<string> { "Please go to user settings and set your phone number." } }
            };
            CustomValidation?.DisplayErrors(errors);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data.Add("Category", typeof(ConfirmPhone));
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: That style is suitable for WinForms, not Blazor. Even in WPF it works but MVVM is preferable. Blazor is essentially React# so instead of trying to modify controls directly, have them bind to parameters. That's why all samples show loading objects and setting fields in `InitializeAsync` *then* having the UI elements update themselves based on the properties/fields they bind to

Comment: Just like React, `CustomValidation` should bind to the data it needs, then handle its own processing. Data flows down (through data binding/parameters) actions flow up (through events/callbacks)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But don't I have to wait for Blazor to bind my parameter `CustomValidation` to my element `CustomValidation` before I can do anything with it? Also, based on this comment, is it a bad practice to name a parameter the same as the component? It generally seems to fit but it can make for confusing discussion.

Comment: Inside the component? No. When the component is created, Blazor itself will bind the parameters from the outer component to `CustomValidation`'s parameters. Inside `CustomValidation.OnParametersSetAsync` you can validate the data just added, modified the state (fields, errors) and Blazor will update the error display.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Well then when/where can I safely access `CustomValidation`? I need to add any errors from the initial values to CustomValidation to show that to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some meat to @HH's answer.

I'm assuming there's no code or `await` yields in `OnInitializedAsync`.

When you first try to execute:

```cs
 CustomValidation?.ClearErrors();
```

The page component hasn't rendered and the `CustomValidation` component doesn't exist.  You can't initialize it, it's a component and managed by the Renderer.  So don't try and use it till the page had rendered at least once.

Once this line executes,  if it await yields, `OnParametersSetAsync` yields.

```cs
var user = (await LoggedInUser.GetCombinedUser(Principal))?.IdentityUser;
```

Or, if it doesn't yield [it's a block of sync code in a Task wrapper], then this line [if it yields]:

```cs
ConfirmPhoneModel.DisplayNumber = await SmsService.FormatPhoneNumber(user.PhoneNumber);
```

The component now renders for the first time and the `CustomValidation` instance created by the renderer is assigned to `CustomValidation`.  Which explains your *part way down in the code it is non-null*.

So you should structure your code like this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
   // Do stuff that needs to happen before the first render
   await Task.Yield();
   // Do stuff that needs sub components in the render tree to exist. 
}
```

Or:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
   // Do stuff that needs to happen before the first render
   await Task.Yield();
}

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
   // The component will have rendered so you can access sub components. 
}
```

> Can I not depend an @ref values being set in OnParametersSetAsync()?

No you can't.  You need the component to have rendered at least once.  `OnParametersSetAsync` is called after `OnInitializedAsync` on the first `SetParametersAsync` call.  If `OnInitializedAsync` doesn't `await` yield, then the component won't have rendered when `OnParametersSetAsync` is run for the first time.

> And if so, is the correct place to initialize the object in OnAfterRenderAsync()

No, we've both already explained in previous answers what `OnAfterRenderAsync` is for.  It's not this.

> Or am I not understanding something or doing something wrong.

You're learning.  As I've explained in previous answers: get the logic right and everything falls into place.

#### An explanation of what happens when Yielding:

In the component lifecycle `OnParametersSetAsync` is called like this:

```cs
var task = OnParametersSetAsync();
```

so when you call this in `OnParametersSetAsync`

```cs
   await Task.Yield();
```

this basically creates a continuation task containing the code after the yield, and pushes it to the end of the synchronisation context's queue.

This code block from the component lifecycle code runs.

```
StateHasChanged();
if(task is not completed)
   await task;
```

As `task` isn't complete, this block yields all the way back to the synchronisation context, which allows the Renderer to service the render queue [and thus render the component].

Comment: I truly appreciate your comment _"you're learning."_ I think I am but it's slow and painful. On to your answer, can I assume after the call to `await Task.Yield();` that CustomValidation will then be set? If so, then all this stuff does belong in `OnInitializedAsync`, after the yield - correct?

Comment: Yes, because the component has rendered, the renderer has created the instance of `CustomValidation` and assigned the instance to the `CustomValidation` variable.  See my explanation in the answer.  You know my answer to the last question!  I'm sure someone will point out an exception, but if you have to write standard C# logic in `OnAfterRenderAsync` then you've not got your logic right!

Comment: I remember it being slow and painful when I first started.  You might like to look at this resource which walks through how to build a `ComponentBase` equivalent - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Components/blob/master/Tutorials/Exploring-Components/Introduction.md.  It's a good exercise in learning how it really works.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I not depend an @ref values being set in OnParametersSetAsync()?

No, not really. An `@ref` will be compiled into a simple assignment inside the `override BuildRenderTree()` .

So the variable CustomValidation will be set during the first render, which happens after or during OnParametersSetAsync().

> is the correct place to initialize the object in OnAfterRenderAsync()?

That would be awkward, and contradict the use of OnParametersSetAsync(). Do you really have a component with parameters here? That change during the lifetime of the component?

The problem stems from needing the Validator before rendering. That shouldn't normally be necessary. Try to get rid of that.

Comment: I added more specifics above. I think use case #2 can be handled in OnParametersSetAsync although your comment worries me that that is wrong. And for use case #1, I'm at a loss as to where else to do this. Any suggestions? TIA